# Froogaloop Failed to load resource

Tags: jquery, vimeo, froogaloop

I am using the current versions of Jquery and Froogaloop. The issue is not detrimental, the videos still play, but whenever you try to scrub the video (in Firefox), the video goes away and I get an oh so helpful error on the vimeo video saying "There was an error encountered while loading this video". In the JS console I get "Failed to load resource". It is more annoying than anything, the issue happens randomly in Chrome as well.

Below is my code

```
function init() {
      var source = $('#0').attr('name'),
      title = $('#0').attr('title');
      frame = buildIframe(source, title),
      iframe = $('#player')[0],
      player = $f(iframe);
      player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
      });
      window.location.hash = $('#0').attr('title');
    }
     init();

     function buildIframe(source, title) {       
       $('#player').attr('title', title);
       $('#player').attr('src', ('http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ source +'?api=1&player_id=player'));
       iframe = $('#player');

       return iframe;
     }

     function onFinish(id) { 
        //close the video player
 }


//the html
<iframe id="player" title="" src="" frameborder="0" width="840px" height="358px" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen/></iframe>

<ul id="videos">
  <li id="0" name=VIMEOID title=VIDEOTITLE width="50px" height="28px" >First Vid</li>
</ul>
```

Again it all works except for the stupid scrubbing error, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so through a convo with vimeo they told me this is an issue that is inherit with browsers. You are not supposed to use different DNS for loading resources, so it will work but the browsers won't be happy about it.